# How can I optimize this VBA code to make it more efficient and faster?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization, excel-formula

I attach the fully code below. This code basically calculate the monthly working hours for the employee with the following exception (Cfp,CO,CM,Krank ohne AU,Zlp) but it takes around 20-30 minutes and sometimes crash.I want to know if there is any way I can make it work more efficient and faster.(Im a VBA begginer so don't judge me please).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sourceFile As Workbook, destinationFile As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, sourceRange2 As Range, sourceRange3 As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range, destinationCell As Range
    Dim filePath As String, destinationFilePath As String
    Dim dataArray As Variant, dataArray2 As Variant, dataArray3 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rowMatch As Long, colMatch As Long ' New variables for storing the row and column where the match is found

    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\grupat dupa nume.xlsx"
    destinationFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Foaie pontaj.xlsm"

    Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set sourceSheet = sourceFile.Worksheets("Timetac Export")
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A:A")
    Set sourceRange2 = sourceSheet.Range("C:C")
    Set sourceRange3 = sourceSheet.Range("B:B")

    Set destinationFile = Workbooks.Open(destinationFilePath)
    Set destinationSheet = destinationFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destinationRange = destinationSheet.Range("C5:C" & destinationSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) ' Limit destinationRange to used range in column C

    Dim destinationColumns(1 To 31) As Long ' New array to store the column number for each match

    For i = 1 To 31
        Set destinationCell = destinationSheet.Cells(5, 3 + i) ' Adjusted to start from the first column of "C:C"
        destinationColumns(i) = destinationCell.Column ' Store the column number in the array
    Next i

    ' Convert the ranges to arrays
    dataArray = sourceRange.Value
    dataArray2 = sourceRange2.Value
    dataArray3 = sourceRange3.Value

    Dim matchesArray(1 To 31) As String ' Array to store matches for each destination cell

    For Each destinationCell In destinationRange ' Loop through each cell in destinationRange
        For i = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)
            If dataArray(i, 1) = destinationCell.Value Then
                ' Check if the first two numbers from Column C in the sourceSheet match with one cell value from D3:AH3 in the destinationSheet
                Dim matchValue As String
                matchValue = Left(dataArray2(i, 1), 2) ' Get the first two numbers from Column C in the sourceSheet

                ' Check if the matchValue exists in D3:AH3 in the destinationSheet
                Dim headerRange As Range
                Set headerRange = destinationSheet.Range("D3:AH3")
                Dim headerCell As Range

                For Each headerCell In headerRange
                    If headerCell.Value = matchValue Then
                        rowMatch = i ' Store the row number where the match is found

                        ' Process the matches and add them to the matches array
                        Select Case dataArray3(rowMatch, 1)
                            Case "unbezahlter Urlaub"
                                matchesArray(headerCell.Column - 3) = "Cfp"
                            Case "Krankenstand"
                                matchesArray(headerCell.Column - 3) = "CM"
                            Case "Urlaub"
                                matchesArray(headerCell.Column - 3) = "CO"
                            Case "Sonstige Abwesenheiten", "Krank ohne AU"
                                matchesArray(headerCell.Column - 3) = "Zlp"
                            Case "UAI SRL", "Break", "UAI GmbH", "Pause", "Developing", "UAI KFT", "Winowig"
                                Dim sumValue As Double ' Variable to store the sum of matching cells
                                sumValue = 0 ' Initialize the sum to zero
                                Dim k As Long
                                For k = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)
                                    If dataArray(k, 1) = destinationCell.Value And Left(dataArray2(k, 1), 2) = matchValue Then
                                        sumValue = sumValue + sourceSheet.Cells(k, 6).Value
                                    End If
                                Next k

                                ' Custom rounding logic
                                Dim decimalPart As Double
                                decimalPart = sumValue - Int(sumValue) ' Extract the decimal part of the sumValue

                                If decimalPart <= 0.49 Then
                                    sumValue = Int(sumValue) ' Round down to the nearest integer
                                ElseIf decimalPart >= 0.51 Then
                                    sumValue = Int(sumValue) + 0.5 ' Round up to the nearest 0.50 increment
                                End If

                                matchesArray(headerCell.Column - 3) = sumValue

                            ' Add more cases as needed...
                            Case Else
                                ' No match found, do nothing for this case
                        End Select
                    End If
                Next headerCell
            End If
        Next i

        ' Write the matches to the corresponding columns in the destination sheet
        For j = 1 To 31
            If matchesArray(j) <> "" Then
                destinationSheet.Cells(destinationCell.Row, destinationColumns(j)).Value = matchesArray(j)
            End If
        Next j

        ' Clear the matches array for the next destination cell
        Erase matchesArray
    Next destinationCell

    ' Optional: Display a message box indicating the process is complete
    MsgBox "No, îi gata!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

I tried to change the line from this `destinationSheet.Range("C5:C" & destinationSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)` to this `destinationSheet.Range("C5:C" & destinationSheet.Cells(1000, "C").End(xlUp).Row)` because I thought it will reduce the number of looping through column C cells making it faster.

Comment: The 3 lines after `' Check if the matchValue exists in D3:AH3 in the destinationSheet`- I'm not sure they should be inside the loop as `destinationSheet` doesn't change?

Comment: In fact, there's a few `Dim` lines that don't need to be inside loops there.

Comment: Most of your comparisons are being done with arrays which will help, except for `destinationRange` and  `headerRange`. Consider copying those ranges to arrays at the start and performing your tests and changes on the array contents and then writing back the array to the range at the end.

Comment: You may also want to change Value2, unless you are storing dates or currencies   `dataArray = sourceRange.Value2`. And maybe transform that `For Each` into a `For` loop inside another array  for `destinationCell `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without seeing your data, however, one thing that leaps out is that you are setting the 3 'dataArray's based on the 3 'sourceRange's and each of the 'sourceRange's, in modern Excel, will consist of over 1 million items (i.e. one for each row in the Worksheet). Assuming you do not actually use every row in the Worksheet (and **importantly** assuming that you have at least 2 rows of data in the Worksheet) then you can limit the rows / items being processed by changing these 3 lines:

```
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A:A")
Set sourceRange2 = sourceSheet.Range("C:C")
Set sourceRange3 = sourceSheet.Range("B:B")
```

to these

```
Set sourceRange = Intersect(sourceSheet.Range("A:A"), sourceSheet.UsedRange)
Set sourceRange2 = Intersect(sourceSheet.Range("C:C"), sourceSheet.UsedRange)
Set sourceRange3 = Intersect(sourceSheet.Range("B:B"), sourceSheet.UsedRange)
```

Again, without seeing your data it is hard to know if this is going to provide a material performance improvement, but please try and advise the outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much, this make it run in less than 5 seconds